What is the alpha parameter for L1 normalization in scikit-learn QuantileRegressor
An example in the documentation for scikit-learn Quantile Regression shows an example where a parameter alpha is set to zero. The default is 1.
The documentation for QuantileRegressor shows the default value set to 1.0. It states that this is a regularization constant that multiples an L1 penalty term.
I do not have an intuitive understanding of what the Lasso is, or what L1 regression means exactly.
Is there an intuitive explanation for how the parameter alpha relates to these things?
There is a wikipedia article related to Quantile Regression which is quite detailed. Scanning through this, it looks like alpha is lambda in the section Choice of Regularization Parameter. It may also be refered to as t elsewhere.
My intuition here could be wrong.
My conclusion thus far is that alpha probably only has an effect in multiple dimension (> 1) regression problems, and it might be used to select a subset of dimensions, that is, the most significant dimensions which have the most statistically predictive power?

"I do not have an intuitive understanding of what the Lasso is, or what L1 regression means" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)
